# I saved data inito dataStore from activity A (settings activity) . How to access that same data from Activity B (Main Activity)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-jetpack-datastore

I'm saving some data in dataStore from my settings activity and then when I close it I should be able to access that same data from any other activity. When I tried to do so it is giving me the following error:

[image: image of error]

Description of exactly what I did:

1. First I saved data in dataStore from settings activity (Activity B) at that time I had not created any instance of data Store in my main activity (Activity A)
2. Then I created and instance in main activity using which I was able to read data from data store.
3. But after that I'm not able to store/update data into data Store from the settings activity

I think im doing it the wrong way please provide a solution or refer me towards a guide/article which can help. Thank you.

this is the error in text:

```
2023-05-31 06:45:42.453 25399-25399 AndroidRuntime com.hemant.pomoapp E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hemant.pomoapp, PID: 25399
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are multiple DataStores active for the same file: /data/user/0/com.hemant.pomoapp/files/datastore/settings.preferences_pb. You should either maintain your DataStore as a singleton or confirm that there is no two DataStore's active on the same file (by confirming that the scope is cancelled).
    at androidx.datastore.core.okio.OkioStorage.createConnection(OkioStorage.kt:57)
    at androidx.datastore.core.DataStoreImpl$storageConnection$2.invoke(DataStoreImpl.kt:131)
    at androidx.datastore.core.DataStoreImpl$storageConnection$2.invoke(DataStoreImpl.kt:130)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at androidx.datastore.core.DataStoreImpl.getStorageConnection$datastore_core_release(DataStoreImpl.kt:130)
    at androidx.datastore.core.DataStoreImpl$coordinator$2.invoke(DataStoreImpl.kt:133)
    at androidx.datastore.core.DataStoreImpl$coordinator$2.invoke(DataStoreImpl.kt:133)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at androidx.datastore.core.DataStoreImpl.getCoordinator(DataStoreImpl.kt:133)
    at androidx.datastore.core.DataStoreImpl.readAndInitOrPropagateAndThrowFailure(DataStoreImpl.kt:216)
    at androidx.datastore.core.DataStoreImpl.handleUpdate(DataStoreImpl.kt:195)
    at androidx.datastore.core.DataStoreImpl.access$handleUpdate(DataStoreImpl.kt:46)
    at androidx.datastore.core.DataStoreImpl$writeActor$3.invokeSuspend(DataStoreImpl.kt:159)
    at androidx.datastore.core.DataStoreImpl$writeActor$3.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
    at androidx.datastore.core.DataStoreImpl$writeActor$3.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
    at androidx.datastore.core.SimpleActor$offer$2.invokeSuspend(SimpleActor.kt:121)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@a2d9675, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (25399) for package com.hemant.pomoapp ----------------------------
```

This is the code for activity where I'm saving the data into dataStore Settings Activity(activity B):

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

private var binding: ActivitySettingsBinding? = null

//    val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")
private val dataStore = DataStoreManager(this@SettingsActivity)


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivitySettingsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding?.root)
    hideStatusBar()


    //onclick-listeners for textview and increase decrease buttons

    binding?.tvFocusLength?.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding?.ibFocusLengthInc?.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding?.ibFocusLengthDec?.setOnClickListener(this)

    binding?.tvShortBreakLength?.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding?.ibShortBreakLengthInc?.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding?.ibShortBreakLengthDec?.setOnClickListener(this)

    binding?.tvLongBreakLength?.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding?.ibLongBreakLengthInc?.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding?.ibLongBreakLengthDec?.setOnClickListener(this)

    binding?.tvPomoUntilLongBreak?.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding?.ibPomoUntilLongBreakInc?.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding?.ibPomoUntilLongBreakDec?.setOnClickListener(this)

    binding?.swAutoResumeTimer?.setOnClickListener(this)

    binding?.swSound?.setOnClickListener(this)

    binding?.btnSaveChanges?.setOnClickListener(this)


    //close activity
    val btnCloseSettings = binding?.btnCloseSettings
    btnCloseSettings?.setOnClickListener {
        finish()
    }
}

override fun onClick(view: View?) {
    when (view?.id) {
        R.id.ibFocusLengthInc -> {
            var focusLengthValue = binding?.tvFocusLength?.text.toString().toInt()
            if (focusLengthValue >= 5) {
                if (focusLengthValue >= 60) {
                    focusLengthValue = 60
                } else {
                    focusLengthValue += 5
                }
            } else {
                focusLengthValue += 1
            }
            binding?.tvFocusLength?.setText("$focusLengthValue")
        }

        R.id.ibFocusLengthDec -> {
            var focusLengthValue = binding?.tvFocusLength?.text.toString().toInt()
            if (focusLengthValue <= 5) {
                focusLengthValue -= 1
            } else {
                focusLengthValue -= 5
            }

            binding?.tvFocusLength?.setText("${if (focusLengthValue > 0) focusLengthValue else 1}")
        }

        R.id.ibShortBreakLengthInc -> {
            var shortBreakLengthValue = binding?.tvShortBreakLength?.text.toString().toInt()

            if (shortBreakLengthValue >= 60) {
                shortBreakLengthValue = 60
            } else {
                shortBreakLengthValue += 1
            }

            binding?.tvShortBreakLength?.setText("$shortBreakLengthValue")
        }

        R.id.ibShortBreakLengthDec -> {
            var shortBreakLengthValue = binding?.tvShortBreakLength?.text.toString().toInt()
            if (shortBreakLengthValue > 1) {
                shortBreakLengthValue -= 1
            } else {
                shortBreakLengthValue = 1
            }
            binding?.tvShortBreakLength?.setText("$shortBreakLengthValue")
        }

        R.id.ibLongBreakLengthInc -> {
            var longBreakLengthValue = binding?.tvLongBreakLength?.text.toString().toInt()
            if (longBreakLengthValue >= 60) {
                longBreakLengthValue = 60
            } else {
                longBreakLengthValue += 1
            }
            binding?.tvLongBreakLength?.setText("$longBreakLengthValue")
        }

        R.id.ibLongBreakLengthDec -> {
            var longBreakLengthValue = binding?.tvLongBreakLength?.text.toString().toInt()
            if (longBreakLengthValue > 1) {
                longBreakLengthValue -= 1
            } else {
                longBreakLengthValue = 1
            }
            binding?.tvLongBreakLength?.setText("$longBreakLengthValue")
        }

        R.id.ibPomoUntilLongBreakInc -> {
            var pomoUntilLongBreakValue = binding?.tvPomoUntilLongBreak?.text.toString().toInt()

            if (pomoUntilLongBreakValue >= 10) {
                pomoUntilLongBreakValue = 10
            } else {
                pomoUntilLongBreakValue += 1
            }

            binding?.tvPomoUntilLongBreak?.setText("$pomoUntilLongBreakValue")
        }

        R.id.ibPomoUntilLongBreakDec -> {
            var pomoUntilLongBreakValue = binding?.tvPomoUntilLongBreak?.text.toString().toInt()

            if (pomoUntilLongBreakValue <= 1) {
                pomoUntilLongBreakValue = 1
            } else {
                pomoUntilLongBreakValue -= 1
            }

            binding?.tvPomoUntilLongBreak?.setText("$pomoUntilLongBreakValue")
        }

        R.id.swAutoResumeTimer -> {
            if (binding?.swAutoResumeTimer!!.isChecked) {

            }
        }

        R.id.btnSaveChanges -> {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                saveChanges()
            }
        }
    }
}

suspend fun saveChanges() {

    val focusLengthValue = binding?.tvFocusLength!!.text.toString()
    val shortBreakLengthValue = binding?.tvShortBreakLength!!.text.toString()
    val longBreakLengthValue = binding?.tvLongBreakLength!!.text.toString()
    val pomoUntilLongBreakValue = binding?.tvPomoUntilLongBreak!!.text.toString()
    val autoResumeTimer = binding?.swAutoResumeTimer!!.isChecked
    val sound = binding?.swSound!!.isChecked


    dataStore.savetoDataStore(focusLengthValue)
    val dataStoreValue = dataStore.getFromDataStore()
    Toast.makeText(this@SettingsActivity, "$dataStoreValue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

}


fun hideStatusBar() {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    actionBar?.hide()
    supportActionBar?.hide()

    // For devices with API level 30 and above, use the following code
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
    } else {
        // For devices with API level below 30, use the following code
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )
    }
}
}
```

the saveChanges() method is where im saving the data into dataStore

this is the dataStore class code where im creating the dataStore instance:

```
class DataStoreManager(val context: Context) {

    private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")

    companion object {
        val FOCUS_LENGTH = stringPreferencesKey("focusLength")
    }


    suspend fun savetoDataStore(focusLengthValue: String) {
        context.dataStore.edit {
            it[FOCUS_LENGTH] = focusLengthValue
        }
    }

    suspend fun getFromDataStore(): String? {
        val values = context.dataStore.data.first()
        val value = values[FOCUS_LENGTH]
        return value
    }
}
```

The next is parts of code where I'm creating and instance of dataStore in my main activity(activity A) and where I'm trying to read data using the dataStore instance and after that if I try to save data again in my settings activity I get the above mentioned error and my app crashes

```
private val dataStore = DataStoreManager(this@MainActivity)
```

Trying to read data in main activity:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
        val value = dataStore.getFromDataStore()
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "$value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution for it so If you just make the following changes the app does not crash any more and works perfectly fine.

Make the following change in the data store manager class file.

```
    private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")

class DataStoreManager(val context: Context) {

    companion object {
        val FOCUS_LENGTH = stringPreferencesKey("focusLength")
    }


    suspend fun savetoDataStore(focusLengthValue: String) {
        context.dataStore.edit {
            it[FOCUS_LENGTH] = focusLengthValue
        }
    }

    suspend fun getFromDataStore(): String? {
        val values = context.dataStore.data.first()
        val value = values[FOCUS_LENGTH]
        return value
    }
}
```

Just shift the line where you are creating an instance of `dataStore` outside the class scope. I think what that does is that it does not create a new instance of `dataStore` every time you create instance of `dataStoreMangager` class. So there is only one `dataStore` instance at any time that can access the preferences file.

The solution is very small and silly. I hope it helps.

> Note: Im not sure if this is the correct way or anything. this is what
> works for me in my case.